# How to restrict users from registering in Virtuemart based on their postcode

Tags: javascript, php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am trying to find a way of validating the users postcode when they register against the first three/four characters. I have a local business and would like to restrict user registration.

I have been able to edit much of the php code but can't seem to find where this field is referenced.

It may be that it is controlled by javascript, in which case this probably the reason why as I do not know much about it!

Hope you do :)

Comment: Are you using Joomla?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am using joomla 2.5 and VM 2.66

Comment: I'm pretty sure Virtuemart uses the Joomla registration system, so you might want to look for a Joomla plugin to restrict access to the registration page for specific zip codes.

Comment: Yes I found one but it costs #40 and will not allow the control I need. with the solution below I still get the user info but just restrict them from being able to activate. This way when we do cover their postcodes I can send marketing messages - but many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great, glad you came up with a solution!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this to work by:

file edited: `administrator\components\com_virtuemart\models\user.php`

joomla 2.5
virtuemart 2.66

```
//JASPAL'S POSTCODE HACK


$postcode = $user->get('zip');

if((false !== stripos($postcode, 'PC1')) OR (false !== stripos($postcode, 'PC2'))){
    $postcodematch =TRUE;
    }
else{
    $postcodematch =FALSE;
}
```

then editing:

```
    if ($new) {
        if ($postcodematch == TRUE) $this->sendRegistrationEmail($user,$user->password_clear, $doUserActivation);
        if ($postcodematch == FALSE)  $doUserActivation = TRUE;
        if ($doUserActivation ) {

            if ($postcodematch == TRUE) vmInfo('COM_VIRTUEMART_REG_COMPLETE_ACTIVATE');
            else{
                 vminfo($postcode);
                 vmInfo('Sorry we do not deliver in your area at the moment. We hope to be there soon and shall contact you.');
                 $doUserActivation = FALSE;
            }
```

to restrict the user's registration mail.

hope this helps somebody else!